# What are the uses of self modifying code?

Tags: executable, self-modifying

Is there any real use for **self modifying code**?

I know that they can be used to build worms/viruses, but I was wondering whether there is some good reason that a programmer may have to use self modifying code.

Any ideas? Hypothetical situations are welcome too.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Turns out that the Wikipedia entry on "[self-modifying code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code)" has a great list:

> 1. **Semi-automatic optimization** of a state dependent loop.
> 2. **Runtime code generation**, or specialization of an algorithm in
>      runtime or loadtime (which is popular,
>      for example, in the domain of
>      real-time graphics) such as a general
>      sort utility preparing code to perform
>      the key comparison described in a
>      specific invocation.
> 3. **Altering of inlined state** of an object, or simulating the high-level
>      construction of closures.
> 4. **Patching of subroutine address calling**, as done usually at load time
>      of dynamic libraries, or, on each
>      invocation patching the subroutine's
>      internal references to its parameters
>      so as to use their actual addresses.
>      Whether this is regarded as
>      'self-modifying code' or not is a case
>      of terminology.
> 5. **Evolutionary computing systems** such as genetic programming.
> 6. Hiding of code to **prevent reverse engineering**, as through use of a
>      disassembler or debugger.
> 7. Hiding of code to **evade detection** by virus/spyware scanning software and
>      the like.
> 8. Filling 100% of memory (in some architectures) with a rolling pattern
>      of repeating opcodes, to **erase all
>      programs and data**, or to **burn-in
>      hardware**.
> 9. **Compression of code** to be decompressed and executed at runtime,
>      e.g., when memory or disk space is
>      limited.
> 10. Some very limited instruction sets leave no option but to use
>       self-modifying code to **achieve certain
>       functionality**. For example, a "One 
>       Instruction Set Computer" machine that
>       uses only the
>       subtract-and-branch-if-negative
>       "instruction" cannot do an indirect
>       copy (something like the equivalent of
>       "*a = **b" in the C programming
>       language) without using self-modifying
>       code.
> 11. Altering instructions for **fault-tolerance**

On the point about thwarting hackers using self-modifying code:

Over the course of several firmware updates, DirectTV slowly assembled a program on their smart card to destroy cards that have been hacked to illegally receive unpaid channels. See Jeff's Coding Horror article on the [Black Sunday Hack](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001125.html) for more information.

Comment: DirectTV's Black Sunday Hack?

Comment: [Monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) may also be considered self modifying code. It can be useful when relying on third party libraries.

Answer (score 15):

I've seen self-modifying code used for:

1. speed optimisation, by having the program write more code for itself on the fly
2. obsfucation, to make reverse engineering much harder

Comment: Historically this was quite popular for copy-protection mechanisms on game software.

Comment: which btw was required on some old 8-bit micro (BBC) games to get them to run from disk instead of cassette tape.

Answer (score 11):

In former times where RAM was limited, self modifying code was used to save memory. Nowadays for example application compression utilities like [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) are used to decompress/modify the own code after loading a compressed image of the application.

Comment: I thought these binary compressors only compressed on disk, and decompressed when loaded into memory?

I also read once that because they are decompressed as loaded into memory they cannot be paged out to disk, so they consume more RAM.  Isn't this the case?

Comment: Packed executables have a "bootstrap" application which is loaded into memory and started there. This then loads the compressed data, decompresses it and appends the decompressed instructions to its own code. When decompression is finished, this code is started. Paging happens as usual.

Comment: Self decompressing JavaScript is used abundantly on web pages.

Answer (score 7):

Because the Commodore 64 doesn't have many registers and has a 1Mhz processor.  When you need to read a memory address offset by a value it is easier to modify the source.

```
@Reader:
LDA $C000
STA $D020
INC Reader+1
JMP Reader
```

That's the last time I wrote self-modifying code anyway :-)

Answer (score 7):

Artificial Intelligence?

Answer (score 7):

Because it's really really cool, and sometimes that's reason enough.

Answer (score 7):

1960s-era assembly languages used self-modifying code to implement function calls without a stack.

Knuth, v1, 1ed p.182:

```
MAX100  STJ   EXIT   ;Subroutine linkage
        ENT3  100    ;M1. Initialize
        JMP   2F
1H      CMPA  X,3    ;M3. Compare
        JGE   *+3
2H      ENT2  0,3    ;M4. Change m
        LDA   X,3    ;(New maximum found)
        DEC3  1      ;M5. Decrease k
        J3P   1B     ;M2. All tested?
EXIT    JMP   *      ;Return to main program
```

> In a larger program containing this coding as a subroutine, the single instruction "JMP MAX100" would cause register A to be set to the current maximum value of locations X + 1 through X + 100, and the position of the maximum would appear in rI2. Subroutine linkage in this case is achieved by the instructions "MAX100 STJ EXIT" and, later, "EXIT JMP *". Because of the way the J-register operates, the exit instruction will then jump to the location following the place where the original reference to MAX100 was made.

*Edit:* It may be hard to see what's going on, even with the brief explanation here. In the line `MAX100 STJ EXIT`, `MAX100` is a label for the instruction (and thus for the procedure as a whole), `STJ` means STORE the jump register (where we just came *from*), `EXIT` means the memory location labeled 'EXIT' is the target of the STORE. `EXIT`, we see later is the label for the last instruction. So it's overwriting code! But, many instructions (including `STJ` here) implicitly overwrite only the operand portion of the instruction word. So the `JMP` remains untouched, and the `*` is a dummy token, since there's really nothing meaningful to put there, it'd only get overwritten.

---

Self-modifying code is also used where register-indirect addressing is not available, and yet the address you need is sitting right there in the register. PDP-1 LISP:

```
dap .+1  ;deposit address part of accumulator in (IP+1)
lac xy   ;load accumulator with (ADDRESS) [xy is a dummy symbol, just like * above]
```

These two instructions perform `ACC := (ACC)` by modifying the operand of the load instruction.

Modifications like these are relatively safe, and on antique architectures, they are *necessary.*

Answer (score 5):

Lots of reasons.  Off the top of my head:

- Runtime class construction and meta programming.  For example, having a class factory that takes a connection to an SQL table and generates a client class specialized for that table (with accessors for the columns, find methods, etc.).
- Then of course there's the famous bitblt example, and the regexp analogs.
- Dynamically optimizing based on RT information a la tracing JITs
- Subtype specialization of ada style generic functions in an accretive environment.

-- MarkusQ

Comment: A lot of these involve run-time code _generation_ which does not necessarily involve _self-modification_.  Though that division is somewhat fluid; I can say a JIT is modifying/re-generating other code, but if you view an application running under a dynamic JIT as a whole, the whole is certainly self-modifying.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic linking is a kind of self-modification (patching absolute and/or relative jump locations) ... that's normally done by the O/S's program loader, though.

Answer (score 3):

[Neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) are kind of self-modifying code.

Then there are [evolutionary algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_Algorithm) which modify themselves.

Comment: I am not sure neural networks modify the code. I never knew that. http://www.hoozi.com/Articles/Neural-Networks-Artificial-Neuron.htm

Comment: I believe any change that must be done to the structure of a neural network can be done in the data part. Why should it modify the code?

Comment: neural nets are _not_ self modifying code.  they're nothing more than complex non-linear transformations whose weights are determined by training.

Comment: They don't actually modify the code itself, but the function changes. The same is true for evolutionary algorithms, they can be implemented without changing the actual code.

Comment: What about evolutionary algorithms that are implemented on top of code generators to perform their evolution?

Comment: It depends, both are possible.

Answer (score 2):

Mike Abrash described the Pixomatic code generator for Dr. Dobb's Journal a while back: http://www.ddj.com/architect/184405807 . That's a software 3d dx7(?) compatible rasterizer.

Answer (score 2):

LOL - i've written self-modifying code on two occasions:

1. when first learning assembly language, before i understood indirect indexed access
2. accidentally, as pointer bugs in assembly language and C

i can imagine that there may be scenarios where self-modifying code would be more efficient than alternatives, but nothing obvious leaps to mind. In general, this is something to avoid - debugging nightmare, etc. - unless you are deliberately trying to obfuscate as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Applications which implement their own scripting languages often do this. For example, database servers often compile stored procedures (or queries) this way.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic code generation in SwiftShader is a form of self modifying code that enables it to efficiently implement Direct3D 9 on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Modern example:
I have a script that needs JWT token to work. To request a token interactive login is needed or use a refresh token that is issued with new JWT token. Would be nice to store refresh token in the script and update it each time it is being executed