# Materials for reading various assembly languages?

Tags: architecture, assembly, history

This is a wiki question to gather useful references for learning assembly languages for various architectures.

I recently attempted to read the source code for Basic Pdp-1 Lisp from 1964, and needed to search extensively for reference materials to make even the slightest bit of sense from the code. I feel the links I've collected may prove useful to anyone attempting to read code of similar vintage, like [SpaceWar!](http://www.stibbe.net/History/Games_Speech/Spacewar!.htm)

So a good answer should comprise:

- The name of the architecture
- A non-trivial program in assembly language
  (This is the real focus of the question: a classic program that's worth learning assembly in order to read it.)
- Handbooks and instruction references for understanding the program

I'll start things off with my collected references for reading Pdp-1 LISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**x86 Assembly:**

- [Here](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/art-of-asm/pdf/)'s a manual with more than 1400 pages and some exercises included, some chapters are focused on stuff like boolean algebra and system organization
- Intel's documentation and manuals [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html/), you shouldn't need this before a few years ;)
- [An optimization guide](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf) (quite advanced stuff)
- [Here](http://www.masm32.com/) you can find an assembler for developing win32 apps, both in console and in window. It also includes the windows SDK and a description of all win32 APIs
- [This](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/as_toc.html) seems to be a good GAS (GNU Assembler) manual if you're developing on linux
- [Some examples](http://www.assembly.happycodings.com/index.html) (windows)

Comment: @evilpie, good job adding info to answer, rather than adding a new answer. Keeps things tidy. I +1'd another post of yours (good on its own merits), since I can't vote you up here.

Answer (score 0):

**Pdp-1 LISP**

Pdf of Source including explanatory article, and symbol listings:
http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://www.computerhistory.org/collections/accession/102650371

An ASCII source listing:
http://hack.org/mc/software/lisp.p2

A nice overview:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-1

Pdp-1 Handbook, including instruction set reference:
http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp1/F15B_PDP1_Handbook_1961.pdf

Macro asembler manual, describing how instructions are formed by arithmetic:
http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp1/PDP-1_Macro.pdf

Alternate presentation of instruction set illustrating composability of shift and operate instructions:
http://simh.trailing-edge.com/docs/architecture18b.pdf

This last link is vital for understanding such tricks as the very first instruction:

```
-/Lisp interpreter 3-20-64, part 1
 000004                 4/
-/go
 000004         go,
 000004 764607          hlt+cla+cli+7-opr-opr
```

This could have been written with less obfuscation (but less semantic info) as:

```
opr 4607
```

Or with more semantics (and still more obfuscated) as:

```
hlt+cla+cli+clf+07-opr-opr-opr
```

But since `clf` == `opr` that would be silly.

One last crucial resource for 60s-era assembly programming is Knuth, vol. 1 (1ed or 2ed). This explains some of the more basic self-mutilations that pdp-1 code exhibits.

Comment: See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7452758/733077) for a description of PDP-1 self-modifying code in procedure calls.