# I want to create a simple assembler in C. Where should I begin?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, low-level

I've recently been trying to immerse myself in the world of assembly programming with the eventual goal of creating my own programming language. I want my first real project to be a simple assembler written in C that will be able to assemble a very small portion of the x86 machine language and create a Windows executable. No macros, no linkers. Just assembly.

On paper, it seems simple enough. Assembly code comes in, machine code comes out.

But as soon as I thinking about all the details, it suddenly becomes very daunting. What conventions does the operating system demand? How do I align data and calculate jumps? What does the inside of an executable even look like?

I'm feeling lost. There aren't any tutorials on this that I could find and looking at the source code of popular assemblers was not inspiring (I'm willing to try again, though).

Where do I go from here? How would you have done it? Are there any good tutorials or literature on this topic?

Comment: Something to also think about: Finite Automata to check if the user is even using appropriate instructions, and you will also need a parser to make sure that what the programmer is writing is even correct. Although there is a lot of system-side stuff you will need to worry about, there is also a lot of Theory of Computation you will need to know as well.

Comment: Maybe you should study a package like [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/).

Comment: check out [this challenge on code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/emulate-an-intel-8086-cpu) for 8086 resources and a not-too-short sample program using a subset of 8086 in both source and binary forms. IMO the 1979 Manual is the place to start. ... Also take a look at [my assembly resources wiki question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7203667/), specifically the file "PDP-1_Macro.pdf" which gives a detailed description of a very primitive assembler.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478142/how-do-you-make-an-assembler

Comment: "Assembly code comes in, machine code comes out." -- That's not what "on paper" means, any more than, on paper, raw materials come in, cars come out. But please ignore the nonsense about Theory of Computation ... you don't have to check if the program halts, or even starts.

Comment: If you want to write your own language, you might be better off using something like LLVM rather than starting from the assembler yourself.

Comment: If you have no idea how to start, nor can you use Google, then you should probably not yet making assemblers.

Answer (score 16):

I have written a few myself (assemblers and disassemblers) and I would not start with x86.  If you know x86 or any other instruction set you can pick up and learn the syntax for another instruction set in short order (an evening/afternoon), at least the lions share of it.  The act of writing an assembler (or disassembler) will definitely teach you an instruction set, fast, and you will know that instruction set better than many seasoned assembly programmers for that instruction set who have not examined the microcode at that level.  msp430, pdp11, and thumb (not thumb2 extensions) (or mips or openrisc) are all good places to start, not a lot of instructions, not overly complicated, etc.

I recommend a disassembler first, and with that a fixed length instruction set like arm or thumb or mips or openrisc, etc.  If not then at least use a disassembler (definitely choose an instruction set for which you already have an assembler, linker, and disassembler) and with pencil and paper understand the relationship between the machine code and the assembly, in particular the branches, they usually have one or more quirks like the program counter is an instruction or two ahead when the offset is added, to gain another bit they sometimes measure in whole instructions not bytes.

It is pretty easy to brute force parse the text with a C program to read the instructions.  A harder task but perhaps as educational, would be to use bison/flex and learn that programming language to allow those tools to create (an even more extreme brute force) parser which then interfaces to your code to tell you what was found where.

The assembler itself is pretty straight forward, just read the ascii and set the bits in the machine code.  Branches and other pc relative instructions are a little more painful as they can take multiple passes through the source/tables to completely resolve.

```
  mov r0,r1
  mov r2 ,#1
```

the assembler begins parsing the text for a line (being defined as the bytes that follow a carriage return 0xD or line feed 0xA), discard the white space (spaces and tabs) until you get to something non white space, then strncmp that with the known mnemonics.  if you hit one then parse the possible combinations of that instruction, in the simple case above after the mov skip over the white space to non-white space, perhaps the first thing you find must be a register, then optional white space, then a comma. remove the whitespace and comma and compare that against a table of strings or just parse through it.  Once that register is done then go past where the comma is found and lets say it is either another register or an immediate.  If immediate lets say it has to have a # sign, if register lets say it has to start with a lower or upper case 'r'.  after parsing that register or immediate, then make sure there is nothing else on the line that shouldnt be on the line.  build the machine code for this instruciton or at least as much as you can, and move on to the next line.  It may be tedious but it is not difficult to parse ascii...

at a minimum you will want a table/array that accumulates the machine code/data as it is created, plus some method for marking instructions as being incomplete, the pc-relative instructions to be completed on a future pass.  you will also want a table/array that collects the labels you find and the address/offset in the machine code table where found.  As well as the labels used in the instruction as a destination/source and the offset in the table/array holding the partially complete instruction they go with.  after the first pass, then go back through these tables until you have matched up all the label definitions with the labels used as a source or destination, using the label definition address/offset to compute the distance to the instruction in question and then finish creating the machine code for that instruction.  (some disassembly may be required and/or use some other method for remembering what kind of encoding it was when you come back to it later to finish building the machine code).

The next step is allowing for multiple source files, if that is something you want to allow.  Now you have to have labels that dont get resolved by the assembler so you have to leave placeholders in the output and make some flavor of the longest jump/branch instruction because you dont know how far away the destination will be, expect the worse.  Then there is the output file format you choose to create/use, then there is the linker which is mostly simple, but you have to remember to fill in the machine code for the final pc relative instructions, no harder than it was in the assembler itself.

Note, writing an assembler is not necessarily related to creating a programming language and then writing a compiler for it, separate thing, different problems.  Actually if you want to make a new programming language just use an existing assembler for an existing instruction set.  Not required of course, but most teachings and tutorials are going to use the bison/flex approach for programming languages, and there are many college course lecture notes/resources out there for beginning compiler classes that you can just use to get you started then modify the script to add the features of your language.  The middle and back ends are the bigger challenge than the front end.  there are many books on this topic and many online resources as well.  As mentioned in another answer llvm is not a bad place to create a new programming language the middle and backends are done for you, you only need to focus on the programming language itself, the front end.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is not a tutorial or source code, it's a *specification*. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx

Once you understand the specification of an executable, write a program to generate one. The executable you build should be as simple as possible. Once you have mastered that, *then* you can write a simple line-oriented parser that reads instruction names and numeric arguments to generate a block of code to plug into the exe. Later you can add symbols, branches, sections, whatever you want, and that's where something like http://www.davidsalomon.name/assem.advertis/asl.pdf will come in.

P.S. Carl Norum has a good point in the comment above. If your goal is create your own programming language, learning to write an assembler is irrelevant and is very much not the right way to start (unless the language you want to create is an assembly language). There are already assemblers that produce executables from assembler source, so your compiler could produce assembler source and you could avoid the work of recreating the assembler ... and you should. Or you could use something like LLVM, which will solve many other daunting problems of compiler construction. The odds are very small that you will ever actually produce your own programming language, but they're much smaller if you start from scratch and there's no need to. Decide what your goal is and use the best tools available to achieve it.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at LLVM, llvm is a modular compiler back end, the most popular front end is Clang for compiling C/C++/Objective-C. The good thing about LLVM is that you can pick the part of the compiler chain that you are interested in and just focus on that, ignoring all of the others. You want to create your own language, write a parser that generates the LLVM internal representation code, and for free you get all of the middle layer target independent optimisations and compiling to many different targets. Interesting in a compiler for some exotic CPU, write a compiler backend that takes the LLVM intermediated code and generates your assemble. Have some ideas about optimisation technics, automatic threading perhaps, write a middle layer which processes LLVM intermediate code. LLVM is a collection of libraries not a standalone binary like GCC, and so it is very easy to use in you own projects.